# Is there any way to create a tool with drag and drop mechanism to create a JSON file of intents in api.ai?

Tags: json, android-intent, drag-and-drop, dialogflow-es

I am looking for a tool or a way through which I can create a drag and drop mechanism containing intents messages for user inputs and the respective response to it. It should then be able to create a JSON file of those multiple intents so that I can upload it to api.ai, and my intents are then visible there.

Comment: ```postman``` is the best tool I have ever seen

Comment: thank you, will give it a try! @sudhakar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont know it would help you or not but try postman not entirely for the situation you mentioned but removes a lot of pain from your head https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collections/creating_collections